# Git setup fails to set system config

Tags: git, setup

At the end of git setup on Windows (currently Git-2.28.0-64-bit.exe), setting all system config fails with the following:

[image: Unable to set system config: The system cannot find the path specified]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was because of the following registry key:

[image: cmd Autorun registry key]

I had to temporarily rename Autorun value for git setup to successfully set system config.